# How to create pie-chart within HTML for email-template, so it can work in Outlook desktop version and other Email service in browser (Gmail, Yahoo)

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, pie-chart, email-templates

I need to build a pie-chart like this.
[pie-chart needed to be built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4dLi.png)

I am unable to use JavaScript(JS) for the pie-chart because the Outlook desktop version is not supporting JS.

I made a pie-chart only with HTML and CSS, but Outlook doesn't support some CSS properties like transform, clip...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Email-template</title>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<p>Hello Allex</p>
<p>Here is the summary of you Work Item</p>
<div class="donut-chart-block block"> 
  <div class="donut-chart">
    <div id="part1" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
    <div id="part2" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
    <div id="part3" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
    <div id="part4" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>                
    <p class="center">320 total</p>
  </div>
  <div class="data-container">
    <div class="data-row">
      <span class="data-progress">Completed</span>
      <span class="data-progress-value">10</span>          
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

And

CSS, which I was trying to apply also as inline and internal CSS, because external will not work for certain I think.

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.donut-chart-block {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-self: flex-start;
}

.donut-chart {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto 2rem;
border-radius: 100%
}
p.center {
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-size: 28px;
top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 50%;
line-height: 35px;
padding: 15% 0 0;
}


.portion-block {
border-radius: 50%;
clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#part1 {
transform: rotate(0deg);
background-color: #E64C65;
}    

#part2 {
transform: rotate(100deg);
background-color: #11A8AB;
}

#part3 {
transform: rotate(150deg);
background-color: #4FC4F6;
}

#part4 {
transform: rotate(261deg);
background-color: yellow;
}
```

This is how it looks in the browser.

[image: pie-chart in browser]

This is in the Outlook desktop version.
[image]

I also tried SVG, Canvas, and other things, and they don't work either.

VML (Vector Markup Language) [VML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vml/web-workshop---specs---standards----introduction-to-vector-markup-language--vml-) is the last thing that I have tried, I am not sure is it even possible to make a pie-chart with VML, but one thing that stopped me from trying is that VML is now working in Outlook desktop, but it's not working in browser (Google Chrome).

On the Backend side, it is the C# .NET framework.

So does someone has an idea of how should it be done? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Mailclients support only a **very small fraction of css and html elements**. Thus, you need to code your template html and css differently. Regarding your chart graphics you'll need to convert them to static images. You might find a [framework that facilitates your workflow](https://css-tricks.com/tools-html-email-workflow/). Unfortunately a complex topic with a plethora of pitfalls. See also this [guide on smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/complete-guide-html-email-templates-tools/)

Comment: Normally, when you use VML, you use Outlook conditional code so that the VML only shows on Outlook (`<!--[if mso]>...<![endif]-->)`. Then, you use your other code as well for the other email clients. (You can also do everything except Outlook: `<!--[if !mso]><!-->...<!--<![endif]-->`)

Comment: Here's something similar as a full working example https://codepen.io/matthieuSolente/pen/NWaXwLN?editors=1000